# MOMO Racing Force Feedback Wheel power unit

Tags: controllers

I recently bought [Shift 2](http://www.needforspeed.com/pt_PT/shift2unleashed) and my MOMO Wheel was revived from the basement, but I'm missing the power unit (I do have it in probably my power units box) but the thing is that, I have no idea what is the input voltage and where is the `-` and the `+`

Can anyone that owns one care to give me the correct input unit, thank you!

[image]

Above image is from my Momo Wheel via [Instagram](http://instagr.am/p/NKL4k/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it !

`24v` `0.75A`

from [AC adapters for Logitech Wheels](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9004/~/ac-adapters-for-logitech-wheels)

Comment: you cant accept your own question before 48 hours of its post ;)

Comment: Are you certain about that? Pretty sure I accepted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180016/simplexmlelement-cannot-be-found-when-working-with-namespaces) answer the moment I posted it.

Comment: Enough? http://cl.ly/ACH1 - you coul see that I'm a 14000+ user on StackOverflow, I know what I'm talking about ;)

Comment: If you took the time to look at my link, you would see it is on stack overflow where I only have a little over 200 rep.

Comment: It's 200 rep, not 1000 as I wrote previously :)

Comment: Odd, it's not mentioned on the user privileges. Must be an oversight.